# How to reorder fields in json String in Java

Tags: java, json, string

I receive a `String` with json from an abstract source and I want to reorder the fields in that json so that certain fields come first in specified order and other, uspecified fields can come in any order. Is there a library method that would allow me to do sth like this:

```
// String reorderFields(String json, String[] orderedFields);

String res = reorderFields("{\"b\":2, \"c\": 3, \"a\":1}", new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});

Assertions.assertEquals("{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}", res);
```

Comment: You should be aware that the order of fields in a JSON object are NOT significat. If you need something in a specfic order then you use an array in JSON.

Comment: I need the json ordered for the purpose of human-readability, debugging and logging. It is  really convenient if a persisted json object starts with `id` and `type` in all display and logging situations instead of random properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is solution that should do the trick. It works for first-level fields only. It uses jackson for json handling. Since it operates on basic types only (no custom serializers/deserializers) it should be safe to use for all possible json types.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class ReorderFieldsTest {

    public static String reorderFieldsInJson(String json, String[] fields) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> jsonMap;
        try {
            jsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error converting json to map", e);
        }
        Map<String, Object> resMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Set<String> orderedFields = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(fields));

        for (String fieldName : fields) {
            Object val = jsonMap.get(fieldName);
            if (val != null) {
                resMap.put(fieldName, val);
            }
        }
        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : jsonMap.entrySet()) {
            if (orderedFields.contains(entry.getKey())) {
                continue;
            }
            resMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(resMap);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error converting map to json", e);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void jsonReorder_validInput_reorderedOutput() {
        String src = "{\"b\":2, \"c\": 3, \"a\":1}";
        String res = reorderFieldsInJson(src, new String[] {"a", "b"});

        Assertions.assertEquals("{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3}", res);
    }
}
```

Result on Java 11 and jackson 2.11.3:

```
org:
{"b":2, "c": 3, "a":1}

ordered:
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}
```